# Are these sentences the same in meaning compared to the original sentence?

Tags: meaning

I have been asked to complete the second sentence so that it means the same as the first one. Between 2 and 5 words can be used only (including the word in brackets).

*I arrived on time, although I had left home late.* ***(despite)***

I am sure at least one answer to this will be:

***Despite leaving home late***, *I arrived on time*.

However, can it also be re-written as:

***Despite having left home late***, *I arrived on time*.

If yes, would it be different in meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Either is fine, and they mean the same thing.